# jQuery / PHP: How to make slideToggle open only one row instead of all?

Tags: jquery, events, row, slidetoggle

I've one little problem with my table, coded with DIVs. If I click on a row, it opens every row, but I only want to open the one I clicked, logically. Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/autodidact/QPP5S/11/

**Problem-code**

```
<div class="table">
<div class="table_headline">
<div class="cell_1">When?</div>
<div class="cell_2">What?</div>
<div class="cell_3">Who?</div>
<div class="cell_4">Where?</div><br>
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="cell_1">Date</div>
<div class="cell_2">Concert</div>
<div class="cell_3">Artist #1 + Artist #2 + Artist #3</div>
<div class="cell_4">Venue</div><br>
</div>
<div class="info">Infos</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="cell_1">Date</div>
<div class="cell_2">Concert</div>
<div class="cell_3">Artist #1 + Artist #2 + Artist #3</div>
<div class="cell_4">Venue</div><br>
</div>
<div class="info">Infos</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="cell_1">Date</div>
<div class="cell_2">Concert</div>
<div class="cell_3">Artist #1 + Artist #2 + Artist #3</div>
<div class="cell_4">Venue</div><br>
</div>
<div class="info">Infos</div>
</div>

<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$('.row').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.table').find('.info').slideToggle();
})
})
</script>
```

**Edit:** I am using PHP to get all events. So the fiddle-code is just an example.

**Edit #2:** Added the problem-code

Comment: Please post the problem code in your post as well as the link to jsfiddle (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace `.closest('.table').find('.info')` with `.next('.info')`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8QqCh/

You were selecting all elements with a class of `.info` instead of just the next element.

Check the jQuery documentation for [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
$(this).closest('.table').find('.info').slideToggle();
```

for this:

```
$(this).next().slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the jquery selector instead:

```
$('.row').on('click', function() {        
    $(this).next('.info').slideToggle();  
})
```